# probability to unlock a safe with $3$ digit code

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A combination lock to a safe is opened with a $3$ number sequence. If there are $30$ numbers on a dial and you are given $6$ of the $3$ number sequences to try. What is the probability that you will be able to open the safe?

What I tried:

First we will select $6$ numbers out of $30$. Which can be done by $\binom{30}{6}$ Now arrange these numbers. There are a total of $$\binom{30}{6}\cdot 6!$$
ways to do this, with only one favourable outcome.

So required probability $$\frac{1}{\binom{30}{6}\cdot 6!}.$$

But answer this question was marked wrong. Please tell me where I am wrong and how do I can solve to get a correct answer.

Comment: You are given 6 though.. how does that factor in?

Comment: My bad  I have edited it.

Comment: But aren't you given 6 of the numbers? Why are you choosing them again?

Comment: I am still confuse How to find total ways.can you please explain me

Comment: Can a sequence have the same number twice?

Comment: I am confused by the statement of the question.  It appears to me that you are given six chances to open the safe.  That is, you get to input six distinct three digit sequences.  However, in your computation, you seem to be creating six digit sequences.  I don't understand...

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the numbers in a sequence can be repeated so that there are in total $30^3$ three-number sequences. We are allowed to try 6 sequences and I will assume that they are all different. In this case the probability is:
$$
\frac{6}{30^3}.
$$